# Python (v3.7.7) Multiprocessing.Process? for .issubset

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a problem where I have an input file of numbers that I'm converting to a list of numbers per line. (`group` below).

From that list I generate another list (`all_subsets` below) of combinations using data from the original list (`itertools.combinations()`).

The code to this point runs really fast, but the next segment `.issubset` is where I run into issues (and at this point all data is in existing lists, so I don't believe this is an I/O issue):

I want to create a histogram tracking every subset that matches not only the given input line, but anywhere in the file.

Length of `all_subsets` is `12,157,823`

Length of `input_file` is `1,079`

Below example is checking each element of `all_subsets` against just one record of `input_file` (`group`), which is fine, but when run against the whole lot it takes a long time.

```
    # The all_subsets list (combinations)
    #                 is already created and in-place ahead of this code
    histogram = {}
    for group in input_list:
        group = group.split()           # converts input string into list
        group = list(map(int, group))
        print(group) # [17, 22, 36, 37, 52]

        for subset in all_subsets:
            #
            # This next if statement is the bottleneck
            #                      --is parallelization an option?
            #
            if(set(subset).issubset(set(group))):        # ***
                subset = tuple(subset)
                if subset not in histogram:
                    histogram[subset] = 1
                else:
                    histogram[subset] = histogram[subset] + 1 
        print(histogram)    
        """                   { ( 17, 22, 36, 37, 52 ): 1,
                                ( 17, 22, 36, 37 ):     1,
                                ( 17, 22, 36, 52 ):     1,
                                ( 17, 22, 37, 52 ):     1,
                                ( 17, 36, 37, 52 ):     1,
                                ( 22, 36, 37, 52 ):     1,
                                ( 17, 22, 36 ):         1,
                                ( 17, 22, 37 ):         1,
                                ( 17, 22, 52 ):         1,
                                ( 17, 36, 37 ):         1,
                                ( 17, 36, 52 ):         1,
                                ( 17, 37, 52 ):         1,
                                ( 22, 36, 37 ):         1,
                                ( 22, 36, 52 ):         1,
                                ( 22, 37, 52 ):         1,
                                ( 36, 37, 52 ):         1,
                                ( 17, 22 ):             1,
                                ( 17, 36 ):             1,
                                ( 17, 37 ):             1,
                                ( 17, 52 ):             1,
                                ( 22, 36 ):             1,
                                ( 22, 37 ):             1,
                                ( 22, 52 ):             1,
                                ( 36, 37 ):             1,
                                ( 36, 52 ):             1,
                                ( 37, 52 ):             1,
                                ( 17, ):                1,
                                ( 22, ):                1,
                                ( 36, ):                1,
                                ( 37, ):                1,
                                ( 52, ):                1
                              }
        """
```

Comment: A) Use lazy generators instead of lists where possible. B) Create and store the subsets as sets beforehand. C) Split the load across processes

Comment: Thanks for the tips. A & B get me some efficiencies, but C is where I just don’t understand enough to do it correctly. I’ll keep trying some things, but if you have any good examples of passing a nested iteration to multiprocessing, all while updating the dictionary appropriately, I’d love to see it. I can’t quite find such an example.

Comment: If all the subsets are pre-calculated and read only, place them in shared memory and split the input to several chunks to be fed to a separate process each. Would it be possible to avoid scanning the whole list of subsets and determine if an input row is a superset just by lookup? i.e. to make the list of subsets a set of subsets (tuples are hashable)? That way you could use the `in` operator. In other words: if each input row is a subset, i.e. it doesn't contain alien elements, it must be present as a subset in the list of all possible subsets,  you do not have to check if it is a superset

Comment: You were right! I was able to modify things as you described and avoid looking for things as a superset. I need to do more research and get a better handle on the multiprocessing module so I'm better prepared the next time I need it. Thanks for helping me rethink my problem.

Comment: I'm happy to have helped. I have no time to spare these days, I will look into the multiprocessing when possible. Leave the question open,  so others can contribute too